# Creating Symbolic Links in Cyberduck?

Tags: linux, ftp, symbolic-link, sftp, cyberduck

With SFTP, Cyberduck supports creating a symlink by right clicking a file or folder, and selecting create symlink. This then creates a symlink in the same folder as the file/folder you're linking to. The symlink's path is relative, so it cannot be moved outside the folder, or it stops working.

This is THE most useless thing I can possibly imagine. Why would you EVER want to create a symbolic link to another folder in the same directory?

I have to be missing something. How can I create a symlink OUTSIDE of my current directory in Cyberduck? Or please refer me to a SFTP/FTP client that can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been discussed in ticket [#8570](https://trac.cyberduck.io/ticket/8570). To change the default from Cyberduck creating relative symbolic link targets you will need to set the [hidden preference](https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/en/howto/preferences#Hiddenconfigurationoptions) `sftp.symlink.absolute` to `true` to switch to absolute symbolic link targets.

Comment: Thanks. But I can't find user.config. It's not in /appdata/roaming/cyberduck, and I don't understand the path on the wiki page.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command in Terminal:

```
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/ch.sudo.cyberduck.plist sftp.symlink.absolute true
```

This makes it so that the symbolic links you create use **absolute paths** instead of relative paths.